# Why does FastCopy create exact copies of files that have different folder counts?

Tags: windows, filesystems, file-transfer

I use FastCopy everyday to backup all the files on my D drive to an E drive of the same capacity. But when I select and compare the files, everything matches up except for the folder count. What is that about?

[image]

Note: The files selected for comparison are all personal, none are hidden or system files.

Comment: Does the backup delete folders that no longer exist on D drive?

Comment: Hey there, sorry I'm not sure what you mean. If the folder doesn't exist on D, wouldn't it not be counted on D either?

Comment: Try to apply attributes in E: drive with command `attrib /s /d *.* -r -h -s`

Comment: As @music2myear alluded to, there are most likely empty folders in the source that FastCopy is not copying to the destination.

Comment: Hey Biswapriyo, very sorry, I'm not familiar with this so I don't know what to apply attributes on, and how, or what it can do?

Comment: Hi Bill Oertell, ah that could be it. I'll check if my settings do that.

Comment: OK wow, it really does leave out empty folders. Is there a way to force FastCopy to copy everything? The copy setting I'm using now is Sync.

Comment: Wait, I found it. Guess it's time to answer my own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## FastCopy has an option that leaves out empty folders

By default, this option is checked. So if the copy job has filters checked as well, empty folders will not be copied over. To solve this, simply uncheck the option and apply.

[image]

[image]

More info can be found under **Settings > Copy/Move options** on 
[FastCopy's official page](https://ipmsg.org/tools/fastcopy.html.en)